# How to split 2-dimensional array into two 1-dimensional arrays(C#)?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, split

I have the following array:

```
byte[][] result = service.ToPPC("somefile.zip", 50);
```

When I debug, the value of the result variable is:

```
{byte[4][]}
```

I want to get only the dimension with 4 between sqare brackets. The dimension with no number between the sqare brackets I don't need it.

Comment: that is saying that you have an array of `4` * `byte[]`s (of unknown length, can be jagged - i.e. different each time). How do you want to get 2? what would this look like? what is the result here? Note: that *isn't* a 2-dimensional array; it is a 1-dimensional array (vector) ***of*** arrays (vectors)

Comment: for example: let's say the data is `byte[][] result = new byte[4][] { new byte[] {1,2,3}, new byte[0], null, new byte[] {4,5} };` -  which is perfectly valid for `byte[4][]` - what would the result be? and why?